How to setup NonceLoader in Google PAL SDK for iOS?
In my app that uses Google PAL SDK for iOS I need to get NonceManager using NonceLoader. This is how I create NonceLoader:
let settings = Settings()
settings.allowStorage = true
let nonceLoader = NonceLoader(settings: settings)

I wonder if I should always set allowStorage to true, or should I check for some permissions (disk access) to get the right value for allowStorage? This property is not well documented.
